# Can't add java overlay via layman

Tags: java, git, gentoo, overlays

Can't add *java* overlay via layman. Some other GIT overlays works fine, some don't. For example *yac* and *twister* work, *tocaro* and *vps* don't work.

Layman version: app-portage/layman-2.0.0-r3

```
Agnes liso # layman -a java

* Adding overlay,...
* Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman  && /usr/bin/git clone git://git.overlays.gentoo.org/proj/java.git /var/lib/layman/java )
Cloning into '/var/lib/layman/java'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.overlays.gentoo.org/proj/java.git/': SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'git.overlays.gentoo.org'
* Failure result returned from Git
* Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/java  && /usr/bin/git config user.name "layman" )
* [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/layman/java'
* 
* Trying next source of listed sources...
* Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman  && /usr/bin/git clone http://git.overlays.gentoo.org/gitroot/proj/java.git/ /var/lib/layman/java )
Cloning into '/var/lib/layman/java'...  
fatal: repository 'https://overlays.gentoo.org/gitroot/proj/java.git/' not found
* Failure result returned from Git
* Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/java  && /usr/bin/git config user.name "layman" )
* [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/layman/java'
* 
* Trying next source of listed sources...
* Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman  && /usr/bin/git clone git+ssh://git@git.overlays.gentoo.org/proj/java.git /var/lib/layman/java )
Cloning into '/var/lib/layman/java'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
* Failure result returned from Git
* Running Git... # ( cd /var/lib/layman/java  && /usr/bin/git config user.name "layman" )
* [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/layman/java'
* Adding repository "java" failed!

* CLI: Errors occurred processing action add
* Adding repository "java" failed!
```

I guess GIT works fine. Can somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to report it to the issue tracker